# Import XML into SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, import, sql-server-express

How to get the load time of an XML file in a column xml?

I used bulk insert but does not return to me the load time.

```
INSERT INTO table_test(xmldata)
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Genny\Desktop\standard.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

Is there another way that gives me the time?

How can I do?

For example in Oracle and DB2 `SQLLOADER` and `LOAD` utility directly return the time, is there something similar?

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: Your code is working (although there should be a `\` after the `c:`, shouldn't it?), the only thing you are missing is the actual time used? What are you going to do with this information? Store it, return it? How is this called?

Comment: I have updated the code .
Yes, it works .
I compare the loading time with other utiity other db : sqlloader , load etc.
 In sqlserver what can I use?

Comment: What's wrong with Joe C's answer? You might check the profiler (`Extras -> tools -> ...

Comment: I find a tool like sql loader and load but I don't understand which in sqlserver.

Comment: Again my question: What are you going to do with this information? Is this your private investigation? Do you need to store / monitor / display / return / whatever ? How is this called (part of a bigger procedure or a single call and from which kind of application?)

Comment: private investigation for illustration

Comment: For *private investigation* Joe C's answer should be perfectly fine... If you want, you can store several call durations from may different calls and calcluate an average. Don't really know, what better a tool could be...

Comment: but this is not a tool like sql loader in oracle

Comment: Well - uhm - what?

Comment: you think that this can be considered as similar to SQLLOader to make a comparison?

Comment: No, I think this as just not important enough to worry about. Maybe I don't know enough about this... Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

You could look into execution stats: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx

**Something simpler:**

```
Declare @StartTime DateTime2 = getDate()

your query...

Select datediff(ms, @StartTime, getdate())
```

Comment: I want the load time of bulk and not the total query how can I do ?

Comment: For the load time on an executed query I can only recommend looking at execution stats but that query may be gone from the history by now depending on your settings.  If you want an estimated load time without running the query, thats something I never looked into.  I always do my own benchmarking with real queries.

Comment: For example in Oracle and DB2 SQLLOADER and LOAD utility directly return the time, is there something similar?

Comment: SET STATICS TIME ON  is it equal ??

Comment: Hi Joe C, I vote yours up, as I think, this is the best approach to measure a call's duration...

Comment: @Genny, I found SET STATICS TIME ON as well.  This may suit your needs, depending on how you are calling this.  Based on what I read it should pass a string back that you can then parse.